# Soft Question : Is there any website for weak negative results?

Tags: research

I have noticed that while doing research in computer science you come across many weak but negative results. Now, not every negative result deserves a paper of its own. So I was wondering, is there a website where people can dump their weak results?

If so, how do I look about on this website?

For example, recently we showed that a variation of the Dial-A-Ride problem is NP hard but that is about all that we have. Now, there is no way for us to determine if work has already been done on this variant of the problem since we don't even know what this variant is referred to as in literature.

A resource that collects all weak results could have saved us a lot of time and saved us from re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such website. Any such website would necessarily have to be incomplete: there are tons of negative results (e.g., NP-completeness results), and they come out all the time. Your only choice is to do a thorough search on the web (and maybe ask colleagues). Even then it's possible you miss something relevant, but research can be like that as well. Something close to what you want is [here](https://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/problemlist/compendium.html), but as you can see, it is very dated and incomplete.

Comment: That's a bummer. But it would be great if someone made a site like this. Maybe something like CS meta where it is a sub-section of the community but where people can dump their research work and the community can help to organize it?

Comment: @Juho "Any such website would necessarily have to be incomplete:" So what? Any compendium of research is necessarily incomplete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Only that even if such a site existed, it wouldn't necessarily contain the problem you care about.